# Read and Write to file in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, file, local-storage

I am trying to create an **offline Todo List** in **Angular 4**.

But I am not able to find any way to store data in a file at Client side using javaScript or Angular.

I am using localStorage of browser right now but it is very slow and it makes my program browser dependent.

please provide a way to create files at client side or any suggestions

Comment: To save you'd have have to generate a file download - and when opening the app you would have to "upload" it to the app (or paste the contents of the file into a textbox that you can load from). As far as I know, there is no way to access the filesystem from JavaScript inside a browser.

Answer (score 4):

```
To download file or save file

    /**
     * Method is use to download file.
     * @param data - Array Buffer data
     * @param type - type of the document.
     */
    downLoadFile(data: any, type: string) {
        var blob = new Blob([data], { type: type.toString() });
        var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        window.open(url);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is not possible and it should not be possible for security reasons. I would not expect any webpage would have access to my file system.

If you are building an offline application and it is a desktop app you might try to check [electron](https://electronjs.org/). But that's only if it is a desktop application, if it runs in the browser then it is just not possible.

Answer (score 1):

We can use IndexDb or websql for offline application.

For more details you can check on following URL

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820391/A-Very-Simple-Example-of-HTML-OFFLINE-Database-ind

Hope this will Help :)